# Using Jquery ajax to load images into a hidden div

Tags: jquery, ajax, each

I am trying to use Jquery to iterate over a group of large images in a gallery and then load them into a hidden div using ajax to make a popup index of these same images. Basically it is a Flip book that needs a page index and i want an easer way to write out the index rather than coding it for each image.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "index.html",
  dataType: 'html'
}).done(function( html ) {

var div = $('a.book img', $(html));

$("#test").append($('<ul>')
.append($('<li class="toc">')
.append($('<a>').attr('href','#')
.append($(div).addClass('border'))
)
)
);
});
```

I am still a novice coder and I need some direction to get it working. This code will output:

```
<div id="test">
<ul>
<li class="toc">
<a href="#">
 <img class="border" src="test.jpg" alt="Test">
 <img class="border" src="test2.jpg" alt="Test2">
 <img class="border" src="test3.jpg" alt="Test3">

</a>
</li>
</ul>
```

Basically I get all the images under the " a href, instead of individually. I need to use the $().each function I think but not sure how to use it with ajax.
I apologize if the question is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$.ajax({
    url: "index.html",
    dataType: 'html'
}).done(function( html ) {
    var ul = $('<ul />');

    $(html).find('a.book img').each(function(i, img) {
        var anchor = $('<a />',  {href : '#'}),
            li     = $('<li />', {'class' : 'toc'});
        li.append( anchor.append( $(img).addClass('border') ) ).appendTo(ul);
    });

    $('#test').append(ul);
});
```

outputs:

```
<div id="test">
    <ul>
        <li class="toc">
            <a href="#">
                <img class="border" src="test1.jpg">
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="toc">
            <a href="#">
                <img class="border" src="test2.jpg">
            </a>
        </li>
        <li class="toc">
            <a href="#">
                <img class="border" src="test3.jpg">
            </a>
        </li>

    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: before your edit i was thinking I could use `$('#test').append(ul);`

Comment: Sure, or `$('#test').append( ul.append(li) );` would work as well.

Comment: This works except I need one a href for one li, not all inside one. I'm working with your code to try to fix this but not yet.

Comment: @Mike - was'nt sure how you where trying to build it, but I edited the answer to do it that way.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Is there an easy way to index the images loaded in this way? I want to load page numbers for each image using the index of that image.